# Excel: For row, if condition met, use to calculate average

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an issue that I suspect has a relatively simple solution.

I want to calculate an average from a range of cells but only for those rows containing a cell meeting a condition.

Take the following data:

```
    A       B        C
1 | YEAR |  VARA  |  VARB  |
  --------------------------
2 | 1990 |  1     |  6     |
3 | 1991 |  5     |  5     |
4 | 1990 |  2     |  6     |
5 | 1990 |  1     |  8     |
6 | 1991 |  2     |  2     |
7 | 1991 |  3     |  1     |
```

For each YEAR, I want to return the average of VARA and VARB.

The results should be:

- 1990: VARA = 1.33; VARB = 6.66
- 1991: VARA = 3.33; VARB = 2.66

As I understand it, Excel doesn't have a FOR command allowing iteration and a subsequent IF statement... so does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe `=AVERAGEIFS(B:B, A:A, 1990)` and  `=AVERAGEIFS(C:C, A:A, 1990)`

Comment: It is common pivot table...

Answer (score 0):

For VARA try to use this formula: `=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$7,E2,$B$2:$B$7)`
[image]

For VARB try to use this formula: `=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$7,E2,$C$2:$C$7)`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*This array(CSE) formula solves the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `H217`:

  `{=ROUND(AVERAGE(IF(COUNTIF($G217:$G217,$G$209:$G$214),H$209:H$214,"")),2)}`
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill across.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*